# Why does owssvr.dll return an empty result for my list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to use [owssvr.dll and its URL API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478653.aspx) in SharePoint 2007 to get some list metadata.  For most of the lists in my site of interest, I can use a url formatted like so:

```
http://hts-app1/compounds/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={F987723C-28A4-47D3-83D7-19094B0267DF}
```

I get back an xml-based list of field metadata for the default view and a list of records in the list.  But when I try to use another guid for a separate list, I get an empty response from the web server.  It's a 200 response code, but the other headers look like:

```
Connection:close
Date:Thu, 24 Mar 2011 17:38:46 GMT
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:12.0.0.4518
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I am pretty sure the list guid is valid, since I can match it with the guid for the list I can see in the listedit.aspx page.  If I also format my url like so:

```
http://hts-app1/compounds/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={F987723C-28A4-47D3-83D7-19094B0267DF}&Query=*
```

with the `Query=*` parameter, I can get valid xml, but it's just showing everything, and not filtered for my view, and I'd really like to have the view.

I looked in the SharePoint log file, and I couldn't find anything that looked related to this request.

So, how can I debug this?  I'd really like to use a simple http GET request to get back this metadata, and owssvr.dll seemed the ideal mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a specific view as well. Like this

```
http://{0}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={1}&view={2}&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

for example:

```
https://foo.com/extranet/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=%7B7F7AFB9D%2D6D5D%2D4626%2DBD9D%2D085957DB79AB%7D&view=%7B111EC07E%2DF648%2D443B%2D8DE6%2DB53786BE6762%7D&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

The absolute easiest way to get the list and view guids is to goto edit the view and snatch the list & view info directly from the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** That supplying GUID in the querystring of your URL works for one list and does not for other is probably because the lists are on different sites. Verify that the sitename is correct and that GUID is a List ID indeed.

Be wary of the fact that, however, above applies to both SharePoint 2007 and 2010, for SharePoint 2010 additional measures might be required depending on context from which you execute commands on `owssvr.dll`.

**2.**
`query=*` is not a filter parameter; it shows schema as well as data for all available columns in the list, including SharePoint internal columns, which normally you **never** get to see in ways other than programmatic access.

**3.**
To get only those columns that are visible in the **current *default* view** call display command on `owssvr.dll` while xmldata parameter is set true; like this:

`http://hts-app1/compounds/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={F987723C-28A4-47D3-83D7-19094B0267DF}&XMLDATA=TRUE`

Again this is for SharePoint 2007 only and depends on execution context.

**4.**

> with the Query=* parameter, I can get
>   valid xml, but it's just showing
>   everything, and not filtered for my
>   view, and I'd really like to have the
>   view.

Oh but this is not called filtering; filtering is only based on columns values. For this use additional FilterField1 and FilterValue1 parameters.

```
http://hts-app1/compounds/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll"
            + "?Cmd=Display&List={F987723C-28A4-47D3-83D7-19094B0267DF}"
            + "&XMLDATA=TRUE&FilterField1=YOUR_FILTER_COLUMN_NAME&FilterValue1"
            + YOUR_FILTER_COLUMN_VALUE
```

Takeoff "(double quotes) and +(plus) and (returns) before testing in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am sure the guids are correct because I can see the correct list metadata when I add the `query=*` in the url. The lists are both in the same SPWeb. As for your #2 point, I agree. I ultimately don't want to use `Query=*`, but I just wanted to show that I can indeed get the correct raw list data in this way. I tried your #3 suggestion and got the same behavior as with no `Cmd` parameter. For #4, my list's default view is indeed row filtered based on a field value (as well as including fewer columns for display), which is one key reason I want to use the view here.